# SignalR - sending to a number of clients (not a group)

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR in a prototype I'm building. I need to broadcast messages to a number of clients, but there is some logic as to which clients will get which message which is complex enough to rule out using Groups. Instead, I'm basically checking each connected client - if they are applicable, they're added to a List<>. I then send the message using:

```
var clients = DetermineClients(msg);
foreach (var client in clients)
    client.Send(msg);
```

Of course, if I were able to use Groups, I could do...:

```
var group = DetermineGroup(msg);
group.Send(msg);
```

... since the 'Send' method of group appears to basically do the same thing - enumerate the clients in the group and call 'Send' on those. Is this the 'correct' way to do this? Or is there some way to create a temporary group on the fly? The 'dynamic' type of a group or singular client makes it difficult for me to determine whether I'm doing this right. If there is some magic going on behind the scene for optimising a broadcast to a number of clients, I'd obviously rather use that!

Any advice would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 3):

If you're simply trying to send the same message to a number of different clients based on a complex criteria your best bet would be to have a group that contains all of your clients and then query to find out which clients **DO NOT** fit your criteria.  With the list of connection IDs that do not fit your criteria you can do:

```
Clients.Group("myGroupThatHasAllMyClients",myExcludedConnectionIds).bar();
```

Comment: Is that any better (more efficient) that my existing approach of looping through clients? Your suggestion seems a bit counterintuitive; I would filter once only to ask SignalR to filter again. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It is far more efficient.  By looping through clients you're essentially sending a different (even though its actually the same) message to each client.  However with my approach you send 1 message, the same message, to all clients.

Comment: I suspected as much. Still, it seems a bit backwards to me. In my scenario, I suspect I'd be sending each message to a small percentage of my clients. It'd make more sense to say 'send this to A, B, and C' rather than 'send this to everyone but D, E, F, G, H, I, J... Z'. Is this the only option I have at the moment (without modifying the source)? Again, thanks for your replies - very helpful.

Comment: Yes as of now that's your only approach if you want to use the 1 message to many clients performance benefits.